Certain sans article
De « La Symphonie pastorale » d'André Gide (1919) :

Oui, je le dis en vérité, jamais sourire d'aucun de mes enfants ne m'a inondé le cœur d'une aussi séraphique joie que fit celui que je vis poindre sur ce visage de statue certain matin où brusquement elle sembla commencer à comprendre et à s'intéresser à ce que je m'efforçais de lui enseigner depuis tant de jours.

Ne serait-il pas préférable de dire « un certain matin » ? Pourquoi est-ce qu'il laisse tomber l'article ? S'agit-il d'une tournure rare et littéraire ?

C'est une tournure littéraire en effet, on ne risque pas de la renconter dans une conversation courante. Le sens est pour moi identique ici à celui d'un certain matin, un matin sans autre précision temporelle.
The TLFi note que l'absence d'article est exceptionnelle mais donne plusieurs exemples où c'est le cas.

I.− Adj. indéf., var. en genre et en nombre, toujours placé avant le subst. Exprime l'indétermination, qui porte sur l'identité, la quantité ou la qualité.
A.− Au singulier, employé avec l'article indéfini, ou, exceptionnellement sans article.
1 [Le substantif désigne une personne ou une chose concrète] Certain(e), sans abolir l'indétermination de l'identité, individualise, souligne la spécificité (connue ou censée être connue) :
[...]
− [Sans article, souvent pour souligner le caractère allusif d'une assertion] :
1. − Oh! que non! On ne se moque pas d'un préfet, dit en ricanant M. de Riquebourg, choqué du mot. Nous avons certain dossier, avec sept lettres originales du sieur Crochard. Stendhal, Lucien Leuwen,t. 3, 1836, p. 82.
2. ... il suivait par moment certaine ligne du parquet, et puis une autre parallèle, se donnant la tâche de ne pas mettre le pied à côté... Ramuz, Aimé Pache, peintre vaudois,1911, p. 198.
3. ... l'article du Miroir universel, je peux vous affirmer qu'il a été inspiré à certain petit monsieur que je préfère ne pas nommer par une grande firme anglaise de munitions et d'armements. G. Duhamel, Chronique des Pasquier, Cécile parmi nous, 1938, p. 182.
[...]
2. [Le subst. désigne un comportement, une activité] Certain exprime le caractère particulier difficile à préciser ou la faible mais réelle quantité. Il lui parle sur un certain ton; un certain sourire; il faut un certain courage pour lui tenir tête :
− Littéraire, sans article :
8. Les médecins ont encore certaine influence. Ils poussent les infirmières qu'ils ont distinguées. La politique n'a pas encore fait intrusion. De telle sorte que les surveillantes sont généralement bien. Barrès, Mes cahiers, t. 9, 1911-12, p. 177.
9. ... il [Henry James] modérait parfois son « humour », ironie qui trahissait certaine condescendance, mais cachait une tendresse réelle, comme d'un grand homme pour sa nourrice. Blanche, Mes modèles, 1928, p. 151.


Encore Gide pour une tournure comme ça.
